# jQuery-bound event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to attach a 'click' event handler to the first child of an element with ID 'foo' using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). I understand that the syntax for doing this is:

```
$('#foo:first-child').bind('click', function(event) {
    // I want to access the first child here
})
```

Within the handler body I want to access the element which caused the event to be fired. I've read somewhere that you can't simply refer to it via 'this', so how can I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use "this":

```
$('#foo:first-child').bind('click', function(event) {
  alert(this === $('#foo:first-child')); // True
  this.style.color = "red"; // First child now has red text.
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).doStuff()
```

Answer (score 2):

Forget what you read somewhere and go ahead and use the this keyword:

```
$("#foo:first-child").click(function(event) {
  $(this).css("background", "pink");
});
```